# Grabbing all values from list in the second index?

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, tuples

I have a list of size 1141 called lst containing float numbers (decimal numbers). There are 2 indices at each point in the list such that if I call the second index at any of the 1141 points i.e)

```
input: lst[0][1]
output: 15.23

...

input: lst[45][1]
output: 17.11

...

input: lst[1141][1]
output: 23.89
```

I get what I want. Since the list is contains 1141 values, I want to grab all of the second indexes and put them into a separate new list, or preferably an array. I tried something like

```
lst2 = []
for i in lst[0][i]:
    lst2.append(i)
```

but get  `tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I came up with, hope it helps.

```
import random
# create some data (a list of lists)
points = []
for i in range(0, 1):
    x = random.random() * 100.0
    y = random.random() * 100.0
    points.append([x, y])
# store away first and second indices in separate lists
first_indices = []
second_indices = []
for point in points:
    first_indices.append(point[0])
    second_indices.append(point[1])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).